# How to use input data only once in convolution?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am design a CNN accelerator to execute Convolution layers efficientltly.

In Convolution whose kernel size is larger than 1, the convolution starts to execute only if the necessary inputs are prepared in local buffers.

However, the local buffers are too large because we have to memorize (kernel_size * ci * xi) elements in the local buffer.

So my key question is:

Is there any methods such as transformations or refacterizations that can make each input data used only once in convolution?

I have looked at im2col, however, this method makes no difference.

Comment: Convolution becomes pointwise multiplication under the Fourier transform. To get effective use of the FFT the length of the samples has to be (medium) large. There are overlap-add and other tricks that allow to apportion the data to cache-friendly sizes.